# Locally cartesian closed vs cartesian closed

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

If I have a cartesian closed category (i.e. it has finite limits and exponential objects), is it also locally cartesian closed (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category). Intuition (and terminologies) seem to imply the following inference:

cartesian closed $\implies$ locally cartesian closed

(the converse does not hold unless we add the condition that the locally cartesian closed category contains a terminal object)

However, in the same page of ncatlab, the author of the article asserts that "There are categories which are cartesian closed and not locally cartesian closed" (an example $Cat$). Well, my question is the follow why it has been chosen to use the term locally cartesian closed in order to describe a condition which is not weaker than cartesian closedness?

Comment: No. A cartesian closed category with finite limits is not automatically locally cartesian closed. So neither implication holds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not *always* the case that being blah immediately means you're locally blah. For a simple example from topology (which I assume is the origin of the "local" terminology), the [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) on the [hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) is simply connected, but is *not* locally simply connected.

So in general, there's no relationship between being blah and being locally blah. Of course, in practice it's often the case that local blah-ness is weaker than global blah-ness, which is what leads to this kind of (extremely common!) misunderstanding.

So what's the difference between locally cartesian closedness and regular cartesian closedness?

Being locally cartesian closed tells you that each [slice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category) is cartesian closed. This is "local" in the sense that a slice category $\mathcal{C} / x$ is the part of the category "near" $x$. For instance, if you restrict attention to the monic arrows into $x$, you get exactly the [subobjects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject) of $x$.

As a source of intuition, knowing that $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed tells us that "functions spaces" exist. But it's not clear why the existence of function objects in $\mathcal{C}$ would have anything at all to do with each object having a heyting algebra of subobjects.

As a source of concrete examples, the situation is a bit more delicate (or at least, the only examples I know of are a bit delicate. I would love to see someone provide easier ones in another answer, or in the comments). You can find an example of a cartesian closed but *not* locally cartesian closed category [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156437/cartesian-closed-category). Conversely, you can find an example of a locally cartesian closed category that isn't cartesian closed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864916/are-there-important-locally-cartesian-closed-categories-that-actually-are-not-ca).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I've never heard the intuition that slice categories are in some sense a way of looking at the behavior of a category locally around some object, that's a very nice of thinking about things!! do you by any chance know of any references that motivate the slice category in those terms? (+1)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I don't have any concrete references, unfortunately. One way to see this is in categories with epi-mono factorizations. Then _every_ map into $X$ looks like a subobject of $X$, which definitely feels local in this way. Another, following Grothendieck, is to view objects in a slice category as generalized fibrations. Then studying (subcategories of) the slice category over $X$ is roughly analogous to studying sheaves/bundles/etc on $X$, which again gives us a kind of "local" flavor.

Comment: (continued) I remember taking a class with Steve Awodey where he mentioned this with regards to local cartesian closedness, and how it relates to dependent products.... I was going to say that I forgot the details, but I think it was related to my fibration remark earlier? I don't remember if he had anything more to say, unfortunately. You might find something to that effect in [these notes](https://github.com/awodey/CatLogNotes), but I haven't checked to see if he wrote that particular remark down.

Comment: I just googled around and I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/994694/655547) as well, which is a really lovely logical perspective.

Comment: dear @HallaSurvivor, thank you very much for the insight and references! :) I will take a closer look at the links you've shared tomorrow